# Get certain field from returned JSON object

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, json, person-or-group

I am editing a SharePoint List using JS Link.

Within a SharePoint-Column, I would like to display information from another SharePoint column. The source is a SharePoint Person Column (`Entliehenan`).

[image]

When using the following script:

```
(function () {


    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = { 'Status': { 'View': CustomField } }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function CustomField(ctx){
    var ret

    if (ctx.CurrentItem.Status) {
        ret = "<img style='height: 60px; width: auto;' src='~sites/100037/SiteAssets/Ampel/AmpelRot.png'></img><br><br><span style='background-color: #ffc7ce;'>lent to:&nbsp;" + ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenbis + "&nbsp;an&nbsp"  + JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan) + "</span>";
    }
    else if (!ctx.CurrentItem.Status) {
        //ret = "<span style='background-color: #c6efce;'>Kann ausgeliehen werden</span>";
        ret ="<img style='height: 60px; width: auto;' src='~sites/100037/SiteAssets/Ampel/AmpelGRUEN.png'></img>"; 
    }

    else {

    }
    return ret;
}
```

(The responsible part in the script:)

```
JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan)
```

it returns

```
[{"id":"16","title":"Doe, John","email":"john.doe@jdoe.com","sip":"john.doe@jdeo.com","picture":""}]
```

Now I would like to only display the **Title** of the JSON-object `("Doe, John")`.

How to do this?

I have tried to use:

```
JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan.title)
```

and

```
JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan[title])
```

but both return `undefined`.

Comment: If you are using SharePoint Online, are you open to use column formatting? Or is there any specific reason you are using JSLink?

Comment: Hello Ganesh. I am using the classic library view, as the modern has more limits for my generel Use-Case.

Comment: Ok, Is the person or group field in single selection or multiple selection?

Comment: The Source Field: Person or Group (NO multiple choice allowed and persons only)

||| The Target Field: Date and Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try using below:

```
ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan[0].title;
```

There is similar thread on MSDN forum: [How to get people picker value using JS Link feature](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac8cd60e-e38d-4a4d-a859-cec30efb6370/how-to-get-people-picker-value-using-js-link-feature).

Also there is a nice article on Handling field values in JSLink:

[Handling field values in JSLink](https://n8d.at/blog/handling-field-values-in-jslink).

**Update(to Remove double quotes):**:

You can use `replace` function in JavaScript as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156148/i-want-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string):

```
JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem.Entliehenan[0].title).replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. glad it worked for you.